# Comfort or Value of protection?

Tags: spaceships, space-travel

I have always been interested in why do spaceships in most sci-fi films have windows and are very badly protected, especially the hull of the spaceship. Why aren't there extra systems if something goes wrong?

Most spaceships are represented as comfort class ships with lots of unnecessary stuff, super comfy beds, panarama windows and no protection what-so-ever.

I mean, logically I would first make a very well protected ship. I'd build a very strong hull, maybe even a double hull of some kind. I would have reserve engines and collant systems and many other systems. If I had a hyperspace drive, I would protect it from all sides and probably have a spare one somewhere in the closet. I wouldn't have any windows - no, glass is highly penetratable. Or even if I had them I wouldn't risk them beign not shielded by metal plates most of the time. I would definitely have protection everywhere. And I would have shielded shielded by more shields and almost all of the power would be to the shields during flight.

Isn't this the main thing to do when you are flying a ship in space?

I mean, take Passengers for instance, or Interstellar, or the game Mass Effect: Andromeda, or ever Star Trek, or Lost in Space.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question here is supposed to be, vis a vis worldbuilding. . .  That said, most fictional space ships have plenty of protective armour and shielding systems. Star Trek at least has some kind of energy shields; the ships' hulls are very sturdy (I mean, how many times have they crashed the Enterprise onto a planet and everyone walks away from the scene as if it were a fender bender). Star Wars ships have some kind of energy shield plus physical armour for the windows.

Comment: This feels to me like it is more about a story within a world (which is off topic), than about elements of the world. You may want to [Edit] to clarify how this is about building a world, lest this might end up being put on hold and eventually closed as off topic. Compare the recent question [Can a “too story-based” question be saved with the “In a world…” defense?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5444/29) on [meta].

Comment: Films go for visuals. Big windows give a couple of seconds of relatively cheap and visually appealing screen time. It is a huge money saver.

Comment: It's a 'rule of cool'. People like looking at space. So look, these ships have windows! Look at our CG universe!

On the other hand, consider the crippling hull breaches caused by railguns (and even the point-defence miniguns) in 'The Expanse'. 

Ballistics, in general, are actually going to be at least twice as lethal in space, due to lack of gravity and air resistance; so all your armour probably means jack, and its better to focus on mobility?

Comment: This is usually handwaved by having some sort of "Force Field" acting as a space shield.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking and on what basis you want people to answer, but some points.

1. In some cases the crew and passengers **live on the ship** for
   years. So investing in comfort makes sense unless you want their
   efficiency and well-being to degrade.
2. If a ship has super-science force fields and has to survive
   super-science weapons or travel at warp speed, the difference
   between armor and a window is largely academic. For that matter some
   transparent ceramics are hard enough to count as armor. So having a window does not necessarily reduce protection.
3. Empty space is cheap. In a structure large enough the internal
   volume will increase faster than the surface area you need to
   protect. In space drag can usually be ignored, so if the increased
   volume has low density it doesn't matter that much. And lastly, low
   density **is** redundancy. More empty space you have, less critical
   systems get hit when something goes thru shields and armor. And you can replace "critical systems get hit" with "people get killed." Especially, if the empty space is something nobody uses during combat or emergency.
4. Redundancy is invisible. As is usually protection. Especially in
   fiction. How do you **know** there is no redundancy or armor? Ships
   in Star Trek regularly take battle damage without dying so they
   clearly have some redundancy, but we do not really see it. And why
   would we? The story rarely involves the heroic efforts of the crew
   to route emergency power. Sometimes it did, which is why we know
   that ships in Star Trek actually do have some redundancy and their
   hulls are not made from glass.

Comment: To point #4 ... in one of the Honor Harrington books, there are some minor characters who freak the heck out when they find out that Honor is their new captain, because *they* are the guys who run around fixing conduits during battles, and the Great Big Heroine goes through ships like a shaped plasma charge through a goose.

Comment: On the other hand, at least in Star Trek, if the life support systems are damaged then the people onboard start *visibly suffocating* within seconds because... *why?!* Even if you're breathing into a plastic bag, you last longer than they do. Even at the oxygen partial pressure seen at airliner altitude (30,000 feet / 10 km), you have 30-45 seconds of useful consciousness before you pass out due to hypoxia; 18-25 seconds at 40,000 ft / 13 km. (Figures depending on activity level and, likely, to some degree on individual health. Do not try this at home.)

Comment: @aCVn Because *drama*

Answer (score 0):

Transparent aluminum. Aye, that's the ticket, laddie.

LEDs use very little power and so some running lights make sense. It is like charging your phone or running the radio when driving the electric car, the energy ratio between shields and lighted instrument panels is huge.